# What does parameter y do when df.plot(kind='hist')?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I think that the parameter y in the plot method means the y-axis value. However, when drawing a histogram, for example, if it is a height, if I use x='height' to determine the value to be included in the x-axis range, I got an incorrect result, and if I write y='height' , I got a correct result. What is the reason for this?

```py
# right result
df.plot(kind='hist', y='height')
  
# wrong result
df.plot(kind='hist', x='height')
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because a histogram plots the frequency of occurences (divided in bins) of a certain variable. The bins are represented on the x axis whereas the number of occurences for each bin (of the variable "height" in this case) are represented on the y axis.

You do not need to specify the x-axis as it is simply divided into the number of bins you select for the plot (there is a default value for that).